# SSH connection "This account is currently not available"

Tags: ssh, login, accounts

I tried to connect at a SSH server in 3 different ways, but nothing works:

- using putty - after I enter my password the putty window automatically closed, and in the log file there is: "This account is currently not available."
- using *Windows* powershell - I receive the following message:

  ```
  Last login: Mon Feb ......
  This account is currently not available.
  Connection to xx.xx closed.
  ```
- using *Ubuntu* terminal I receive the same message as in case of *Windows* powershell.

In windows I think that I'm on sftp, but I don't know how to change to shell.

I also found [this link](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216385837-Enabling-Shell-access), but I cannot find the mentioned option in *Windows*.

In *Ubuntu*, my user is on `/bin/bash`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/498648/edit) Can you please verify what login shell the user you logging in is using, e.g. under `/etc/password` is the user listed with a `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin` shell? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Chances are, the shell for the account to which you're trying to log in has been set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`, which outputs that text and returns an exit code of `1`:

```
$ /usr/sbin/nologin
This account is currently not available.
$ echo $?
1
```

Since this 'shell' is not interactive, your connection immediately closes when its execution concludes.